# How to drop unused factors in faceted R ggplot boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is some example code I use to make some boxplots:

```
stest <- read.table(text="    site  year    conc
    south   2001    5.3
    south   2001    4.67
    south   2001    4.98
    south   2002    5.76
    south   2002    5.93
    north   2001    4.64
    north   2001    6.32
    north   2003    11.5
    north   2003    6.3
    north   2004    9.6
    north   2004    56.11
    north   2004    63.55
    north   2004    61.35
    north   2005    67.11
    north   2006    39.17
    north   2006    43.51
    north   2006    76.21
    north   2006    158.89
    north   2006    122.27
", header=TRUE)

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(stest, aes(x=year, y=conc)) +
  geom_boxplot(horizontal=TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(~site, ncol=1) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_log10()
```

Which results in this:

[image: boxplot]

I tried everything I could think of but cannot make a plot where the **south facet** only contains years where data is displayed (2001 and 2002). Is what I am trying to do possible?

Here is a [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20145982/2013-01-23_2130.png) (DEAD) to the screenshot showing what I want to achieve:

Answer (score 4):

Use the `scales='free.x'` argument to `facet_wrap`. But I suspect you'll need to do more than that to get the plot you're looking for.

Specifically `aes(x=factor(year), y=conc)` in your initial `ggplot` call.

Comment: Thanks, Justin. I tried that but "ggplot2 does not currently support free scales with a non-cartesian coord or coord_flip". I also tried scale="free_x" with facet_grid but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Using free scales with coord_flip() is not allowed as of version 0.9.3 see https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/673

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to circumvent your problem (with a fairly good result):
generate separately the two boxplots and then join them together using the `grid.arrange` command of the `gridExtra` package.

```
library(gridExtra)

p1 <- ggplot(subset(stest,site=="north"), aes(x=factor(year), y=conc)) +
 geom_boxplot(horizontal=TRUE) + coord_flip() + scale_y_log10(name="")

p2 <- ggplot(subset(stest,site=="south"), aes(x=factor(year), y=conc)) +
 geom_boxplot(horizontal=TRUE) + coord_flip() + 
 scale_y_log10(name="X Title",breaks=seq(4,6,by=.5)) +

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=1)
```

Comment: Marco, thank you. I also explored this option of creating separate plots and joining them. But the problem with this solution is that the the plots are the same height making boxes much taller for a plot with less years listed. Any idea of how this could be fixed to have the same looking boxes for both plots? (screen shot here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20145982/2013-01-24_0949.png