# Removing unused levels in ggplot boxplot with facets AND flipped coordinates?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, facet

In R, I'm trying to make a boxplot in ggplot with flipped coordinates (horizontal boxes) grouped using facets. When I build this without flipping coordinates, ggplot will drop unused factor levels within facets with scales="free", but this doesn't seem to work when I also include coord_flip.

Minimal example:

```
library('ggplot2')
dat <- data.frame(RESP=rnorm(60), GROUP=rep(letters[1:6],each=10), FACET=c(rep(LETTERS[1:2],each=25),rep(LETTERS[3],10)))
```

The normal faceted boxplot wihtout dropping unused levels works (but not what I want):

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=GROUP, y=RESP)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_grid(.~FACET)
```

The normal faceted boxplot with dropped levels also works fine (not what I want):

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=GROUP, y=RESP)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_grid(.~FACET, scales="free", space="free")
```

The faceted boxplot with flipped coordinates (what I want) does not drop the unused levels:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=GROUP, y=RESP)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_grid(FACET~., scales="free", space="free") + 
  coord_flip()
```

Re-arranging the order of the ggplot commands doesn't fix it. I suspect the answer is in some adjustment of the FACET~. formula, but can't solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an issue of ggplot2: [coord_flip and free scales don't work](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/45)

You can read a discussion about this matter here:

[How to drop unused factors in faceted R ggplot boxplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489632/how-to-drop-unused-factors-in-faceted-r-ggplot-boxplot)

[In ggplot2, coord_flip and free scales don't work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052000/in-ggplot2-coord-flip-and-free-scales-dont-work-together)

Comment: Sure, using grid.arrange() seems like a useful fix. It just necessitates making a bunch of plots, which is annoying, but not the end of the world. Thanks for the links.